# Django, inconsistent queryset ordering with pagination

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm seeing inconsistent ordered result as below.

```
 # filter_queryset / get_queryset is standard DRF method 
 # I don't do any customization for those methods 
 delivery_groups = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
 delivery_groups = delivery_groups.filter(
     primary_product=product_id
 )


  delivery_groups = delivery_groups.order_by('-event_winner_condition_met', 'order__user_id')
  page = self.paginate_queryset(delivery_groups)


# DeliveryGroup = Foo 
class DeliveryGroup(models.Model):

    event_winner_condition_met = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey('order.Order', related_name='groups', editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# Order = Bar
class Order(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='orders',
        verbose_name=pgettext_lazy('Order field', 'user'), on_delete=models.PROTECT)


# whole delivery_groups (printing id only)
[12951, 12941, 12943, 12944, 12945, 12940, 12954, 12946, 12948, 12947, 12953, 12956, 12952, 12942, 12950, 12949, 12955, 11245, 11247, 10399, 10900, 11452, 11\
455, 11453, 9230, 9344, 11463, 11462, 11495, 10717, 9164, 9159, 9391, 9901, 11456, 11454, 11450, 9191, 10870, 10545, 11240, 11685, 11683, 11681, 11697, 11699\
, 11702, 11703, 11704, 11713, 11714, 11715, 11716, 11717, 11718, 11720, 11721, 11695, 11693, 11692, 11690, 11689, 11688, 11687, 11686, 11751, 11754, 11752, 1\
1696, 11694, 11744, 11753, 11755, 11745, 11705, 11698, 11691, 11684, 11682, 11748, 11423, 11749, 11750, 11722, 11723, 11700, 11719, 11701]


page = self.paginate_queryset(delivery_groups). # DRF PageNumberPagination

# first page (id only)
[12949, 12950, 12955, 12951, 12943, 12940, 12944, 12941, 12945, 12942]
```

Q1. why the first page is different from the 10 of the whole foos

```
# second page
[12943, 12955, 12940, 12949, 12944, 12951, 12941, 11245, 11247, 10399]
```

Q2. furthere more 12949 is duplicated whereas whole `foos` don't have duplicaates

Below is the same info, just in pdb session

```
(Pdb) [e.id for e in self.object_list[bottom:top]]
 [e.id for e in self.object_list[bottom:top]]
 [12949, 12950, 12955, 12951, 12943, 12940, 12944, 12941, 12945, 12942]
 (Pdb) [e.id for e in self.object_list]
 [e.id for e in self.object_list]
 [12951, 12941, 12943, 12944, 12945, 12940, 12954, 12946, 12948, 12947, 12953, 12956, 12952, 12942, 12950, 12949, 12955, 11245, 11247, 10399, 10900, 11452, 1\
 1455, 11453, 9230, 9344, 11463, 11462, 11495, 10717, 9164, 9159, 9391, 9901, 11456, 11454, 11450, 9191, 10870, 10545, 11240, 11685, 11683, 11681, 11697, 116\
 99, 11702, 11703, 11704, 11713, 11714, 11715, 11716, 11717, 11718, 11720, 11721, 11695, 11693, 11692, 11690, 11689, 11688, 11687, 11686, 11751, 11754, 11752\
 , 11696, 11694, 11744, 11753, 11755, 11745, 11705, 11698, 11691, 11684, 11682, 11748, 11423, 11749, 11750, 11722, 11723, 11700, 11719, 11701]
 (Pdb) bottom
 bottom
 0
 (Pdb) top
 top
 10
```

Comment: Why Duplicates?: You have used an M2M field (or reverse FK field) for ordering. Use **`distinct()`** to omit the duplicates.

Comment: FYI: Usually inconsistent ordering may happen if you don't specify any order in the QuerySet

Comment: I've used Foreign key (not the reverse).. updated the OP

Comment: yeah, but I specified `order_by` before pagination

Comment: It's better to add your actual model with relevant fields rather than just text info.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu sorry, i just did

Comment: You didn't provide the base queryset either which makes it impossible to help you. My feeling would be that you span relation which would create duplicates.

Comment: I just added the base queryset

Answer (score 0):

**Q2 :**

If you display `order__id` from `delivery_groups.order_by('-event_winner_condition_met', 'order__user_id')`, it is normal that you get duplicated `order_id` values : you have a `ForeignKey` between the two models.